# Change text color of a uicontrol

Tags: matlab, user-interface

This seems to be a simple problem but I cannot Google a solution. I have a `uicontrol`, of style `'text'` that I have made. I can change the background color, but I cannot change the color of the *text* that I have. How is this done?

Comment: I think `ForegroundColor` is the property you want to change.

Comment: @David Thanks! Why was this so hard to find?? ><

Comment: @David: I know this question is old, but would you care to make your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like below code:

```
hh=uicontrol('Style','text','Position', [7 20 95 20],'String','Your Text....')

set(hh,'ForegroundColor','blue');
```

note: modify position of text ( [7 20 95 20] ) in order to be appear in your desire place